# Camera view not saved

Tags: camera

I downloaded a model and I adjusted the camera view as desired. However, when I save the file and open it again, the camera view is like it was on the originally downloaded file. Even when I press "Render" the view returns to the old view. Nothing is parented. How is that done and how can I remove it?

Here is the file - http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31636

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the other answer, it looks like you might have auto-key turned off, which would reset your camera to the original position. If you have auto-key ON, any change you make will be automatically recorded, even over old keys on the same frame. So it's not entirely necessary that you delete all the keys in order to reposition the camera; you just need to set a key on the frame you want to render (press "I" and select LocRotScale to key all transforms).

This is just my opinion, but I generally work with auto-key turned on so I can avoid this. I'm also too lazy to want to set a key every time I make a change (I'm an animator; that's a lot of changes), so I let it do that for me. This is more of a workflow thing, but it is certainly something to know about. Good luck!

EDIT: Just remember that auto-key is not specific to cameras. It's a general automation tool that will capture attribute changes throughout the scene, such as a transformation or even a material change. You'll find the auto-key toggle button in the playhead in the timeline (the red circle).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't played a lot with camera options, but I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the camera have some animation keyframes stored.
Open the dope sheet and remove all the yellow square.

Comment: Thanks. I missed to notice that the camera has a red line that is connected to the object. What purpose does that serve (I posted the file)?

Comment: The line is only the camera limit. The problem are the keyframes. Hold CTRL and press Left Arrow two times. Go in the dopesheet and delete alle the keyframes.

Comment: Yes, when I press "Render", the scene is rendered according to the key frames. Thanks.

Comment: @Vladimir the red line around the camera frame means you have "lock camera to view" enabled on the view tab. see http://cgcookie.com/blender/2011/06/29/tip-camera-lock-in-blender-2-58/

Comment: @Cegaton When I make still renders, I didn't know that a key-frame can interfere after changing the view. Thanks for the video.